# Does parametrization possible on selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Is it possible to perform the parametrization in selenium ide or we should go for Web driver?

Answer (score 0):

You can using Variables and the `store` commands: [Store Commands and Selenium Variables](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.html#store-commands-and-selenium-variables).

But if you're trying to loop or have multiple iterations for the same test with different data, then you will need to use the WebDriver instead.

Optionally, you can place the variables at the top of your test and then copy-paste [sic] the test and change the data. Would be a maintenance nightmare if your tests need to be updated. You could also store parts of your test in javascript files to reduce maintenance/duplication. Uses a format like `javascript {*yourCodeHere*}` - see [JavaScript Usage with Script Parameters](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.html#javascript-usage-with-script-parameters).